# Difficulty with AngularJS "module" declaration in Typescript in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am attempting to use Typescript to build an Angular JS 1.3 app, and I am having trouble right out the gate because it says that "module" does not exist on"typeof angular".

I thought this was easily rectified by just including the "DefinitelyTyped" `angular.d.ts` file, but that doesn't seem to have done anything.

My folder structure looks like this...

- application

  - assets

    - typings
    - angularjs

      - angular.d.ts
    - jquery

      - jquery.d.ts
    - app

      - app.core.ts
    - js

      - jquery

        - jquery.js

And my angular `app.core.ts` looks like this;

```
/// <reference path="~/application/assets/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="~/application/assets/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

    ((): void => {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('app', [
            /*
             * Angular Modules
             */
                'kendo.directives',
                'ui.bootstrap',
                'ui.bootstrap.drawer',
                'ui.check'
            ]);
    })();
```

At first I just assumed the paths were wrong, but it doesn't seem to matter what paths I use. If I use paths relative to the `app.core.ts` file, it still doesn't work.

I am using `Visual Studio 2013.4 Professional`, and it looks like this on my screen;

[image: angular error]

Can anyone help me? I'm getting very frustrated already with angular.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but could be related to the fact that the typing files use TypeScript 1.4. Can you confirm VS2013 supports this version?

Comment: Oh thank you! I upgraded the Typescript version and it perked right up! Would you please post your response as an actual answer so I may award credit?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with WebStorm last week so your question rang a bell :) Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest definition files use TypeScript 1.4 syntax. Please verify your [IDE supports](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304) this version.

Comment: Thanks again! I am so happy that it was just an out of date plugin.

Comment: VS 2012 doesn't support the TypeScript 1.4 Tools extension. I am less happy... :(  #corpratelife